# Getting the value of a query into a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi

I'm trying to convert some of the SQL code we use in our projects towards using parameters. Inserting works fine:

```
with SQLDataSet do begin
  Close;
  SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO testtable (keyname, waarde) VALUES (:keyname,:waarde)';
  Prepare;
  for i := 1 to 10000 do begin
    ParamByName('waarde').AsInteger := i;
    ParamByName('keyname').AsString := 'Testa'+IntToStr(i);
    ExecSql;
  end;
end;
```

work fine and fast.

But, I can't get it to work with select Statements.
At first the following seems to work:

```
with SQLDataSet do begin
  SQL.Clear;
  SQL.Text := 'SELECT :waarde = waarde FROM testtable WHERE keyname = :keyname';
  Prepare;
  for i := 1 to 10000 do begin
    ParamByName('keyname').AsString := 'Testa'+IntToStr(i);
    ExecSQL;
    k[i] := ParamByName('waarde').AsInteger;
    Close;
  end;
end;
```

but the value of k[i] just gets filled with 0's. Do I need to keep selecting the old fashioned way, issuing the query, opening and traversing the result set or is there a way when you have a query with only 1 row to select right into a parameter value?

Comment: Could you tell us what type of dataset you are using. eg: TDataset, TADODataset, TClientDataset etc...

Comment: Parameter is fine with the where block, but you can't parameterize the column name.

Comment: @MikeT at the moment it's ODBC Express DataSet, although we also use and are migrating to ADO.

Comment: Delphi ADO had some issues when you put two same-named parameters in one query. The fact that MS declared ADO deprecated and basically cancelled would not help it too. That is your choice of course, but to me migrating to ADO today is rather questionable choice of future.

Comment: @Arioch'The, you're right about that. Delphi's ADODataSet has a shortcoming with same named parameters, but it's not due to ADO. It uses IndexOf to find the parameter by name, obviously returning only the first one. That's an implementation detail which may be wrong in other implementations too. I think it should work fine if you iterate over the parameters and assign the value to each one with the same name, but I've never tried that.

Comment: But I don't think ADO itself is deprecated, although some ADO *drivers* are (for instance MS Oracle driver for ADO).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Data_Access_Components http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810810.aspx -> ADO was not updated since 2003 or 2005 (porting to newer Windows is legacy support, not development). MS SQL server - their flagman RDBMS product - ceasing ADO support oficially. It looks like those J# libraries, that Delphi requires. Yes, they still work, yet EMB have no developers for them nor modern tooling. If you have inherited ADO-based application - then of course go on while it works. But starting large re-work just to do it again as you complete it, no thanks :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The I'm confused, I was under the impression ADO was still current. If not upgrade to ADO, what technology would be more up to date? ADO.NET ?

Comment: if you gonna use delphi - then i'd consider Delphi technologies. built-in DBExpress or AnyDAC or UniDAC - evaluate and choose. They would probably exist while Delphi itself does.
---
Or you may try installing Oxygene aka Prism and move your Delphi code to dot net, then ADO.NET would be current.

Comment: u may also try to radically step aside TDataSet approach like http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/06/27/SynOleDB%3A-OpenSource-Unit-for-direct-access-to-any-database-via-OleDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** Keep doing it the way you do now. There is no reason to use parameters to fetch query results.

**Longer answer:**

You can use an ADOCommand (not sure what the ODBCExpess equivalent is) and execute a `SELECT INTO` query:

```
SELECT
  YourField
INTO
  :YourParam
FROM
  YourTable
WHERE
  ID = 1
```

In a similar way you can execute stored procedures.

However, using parameters is mainly done for making sure the *input* is valid and is treated as a certain type. It also allows databases to use better caching, because they cache the query once and see the parameters as a variable piece.

For the *output* (returned fields), this is useless. The query is already cached even with normal columns. So just execute the query and read its fields as you do now. You can use parameters, but they only add more complexity and limits, without any benefits. These kinds of parameters are specifically useful for reading output of stored procedures and program blocks.

In your specific case, you want to retrieve a lot of fields (maybe all?) In that case it may be better to execute a single query and loop through the results, than to execute 1000 little queries like you do now. Each query has a little overhead for initialization and such, and you save that overhead a 1000 times if you manage to query all the data you need at once. 
Also, if you do that (fetching multiple records of data), there is no way to fetch those results into parameters, so that's one of the reasons why parameters would limit you and thus another reason to use parameters only for input if you can.

**Your results:**

The reason you're getting `0` is because you never set the parameter value. So its value remains NULL. Because you request the value using `AsInteger`, this value is converted to an integer, therefore returning `0`.

The value returned by the query (the one field that is returned) is probably `0` as well. You actually query an expression `X = Y` where X is the value of the parameter and Y is the value of the field. Since the parameter's value is NULL, the expression always evaluates to  false (using the normal comparison operators on NULL values always returns false, no matter which operator you use or what the other value is). Since true and false are usually represented as 0/1 tiny int fields, the field value would probably return `0` as well. But you don't use this value in your posted code.

Comment: Added a paragraph or two to explain why you're getting `0` in the first place.

Comment: I think this is best answer. Sometimes you need to be told that you can't or should do things in a certain way, thanks.

Comment: @GolezTrol , can same (into) be applied to SQLQuery also? into is giving me syntax error with SQLQuery is there anyway to do similar at SQLQUery ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot parameterize the column name. waarde must be column name in table. You should change your code into something like this. (Not tested)

```
with SQLDataSet do begin
  SQL.Clear;
  SQL.Text := 'SELECT waarde FROM testtable WHERE keyname = :keyname';
  Prepare;
  for i := 1 to 10000 do begin
    ParamByName('keyname').AsString := 'Testa'+IntToStr(i);
    ExecSQL;
    k[i] := SQLDataSet['waarde'];
    Close;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You meant `FieldByName['waarde']` rather than `SQLDataSet['waarde']` don't you ?

Comment: Well, then `Fields[0].AsInteger` or like ? Faster and more type-proof.

Comment: @TLama I am used to do this way: SQLDataSet['waarde']

Comment: I don't think the question is about passing the column name as a parameter, but rather about returning values into parameters.

Comment: @Golez - This is from the question: `'SELECT :waarde = waarde FROM testtable WHERE keyname = :keyname';` I think it's trying to set a parameter for the 'waarde' column. Besides, IMHO, you should be sure if it's your downvote reason.

Comment: It may look like it, but I think it's because Pieter doesn't know the syntax he's looking for. If you read the text and the Delphi code, you see that nothing suggests he's trying to pass column names into parameters. With that knowledge, it looks more like he's trying to assign the column(value) `waarde` to the parameter `:waarde` in a  way similar to how it's done in MySQL, for example. So yeah, I'm pretty sure, but I'll be happy to revoke it should I be proven wrong.

Comment: @Golez - One would hope posters would be little more involved with their questions..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz One would hope so. But for some it's hard to express themselves in english. So answering questions here is also a good excersise to take a lot of jibberish and see to find out what the actual question is and what the best solution would be. Something IT professionals should be good at anyway. ;) After saying that, I *really* hope my interpretation of the question is right! ;)

Comment: @GolezTrol , Sertac Akyuz yes, I am trying to return the value (with the where clause it should return only 1 row with 1 column, which I assumed could also be adressed as value) into the parameter and not the Column name.

Comment: I always let information sink, read it again before I ask follow up questions.

Comment: @Pieter - My very humble opinion: you could put a comment to this answer 'I have nothing to do with column names' before waiting for 2 hours, and then edit your question since 'SELECT :waarde = waarde ...' does not make any sense.

Comment: @PieterB why do u need to make 10k separate requests ? Cannot you do it with one multi-line request instead ?

Comment: @Arioch'The this is a test, in production the values will be accessed randomly by keyname.